# d3.js voronoi.clipExtent() is returning the error: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm setting up a voronoi diagram in d3.js and the function `.clipExtent( [params] )` keeps returning the console error `undefined is not a function`, yet I've been using examples as guides and can't figure out what's wrong. Without `clipExtent()` the voronoi returns the polygon array as expected.

```
var voronoiTopLeft = [ -1 * ( SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 ), SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 ];
var voronoiBottomRight = [ SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, -1 * ( SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 ) ];
clickVoronoi = d3.geom.voronoi( points );
clickVoronoi.clipExtent( [ voronoiTopLeft, voronoiBottomRight ] );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling it wrong.  See this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4237768).

You chain it on your `d3.geom.voronoi` call:

```
var clickVoronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
  .clipExtent([ voronoiTopLeft, voronoiBottomRight ])(points);
```

Or a littler more verbosely:

```
var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
      .clipExtent([ voronoiTopLeft, voronoiBottomRight ]);
var clickVoronoi = voronoi(points);
```